# Can f have a finite limit at infinity?

Tags: functions

The function $ f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable such that $f(0)=0$ and $(1+x^2)f'(x)\geq{1+(f(x))^2}$ for every $ x\in \mathbb R$ . Can $f$ have a finite limit at infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Cauchy's problem $\left(1+x^2\right)y'=1+y^2$ with initial value $y\left(x=0\right)=0$. Then we have 
$$\frac{y'}{1+y^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
whence after integration
$$y\left(x\right)=x.$$

Now we prove that $f\geq y$.
Let $I=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f\left(x\right)\geq y\left(x\right)\}$.
$I\neq \emptyset$ because $0\in I$. As $f$ and $y$ are differentiable, they are continuous and if $\left(x_n\right)$ is a convergent sequence in $I$, then $f\left(x\right)=\lim f\left(x_n\right)\geq\lim y\left(x_n\right)= y\left(x\right)$ so $I$ is closed.
Now, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $0<\eta<\varepsilon$ such that
$$f\left(\varepsilon\right)
=f\left(\varepsilon\right)-f\left(0\right)
=f'\left(\eta\right)\left(\varepsilon-0\right)
=f'\left(\eta\right)\varepsilon
=f'\left(\eta\right)y\left(\varepsilon\right)$$ and then
$$f\left(\varepsilon\right)
=\frac{1+f\left(\eta\right)^2}{1+\eta^2}y\left(\varepsilon\right)
\geq y\left(\varepsilon\right)$$

since $f\left(\eta\right)\geq\eta$ (because $f'\left(0\right)\geq1$ and hence $f$ is increasing). Do the same for $\varepsilon<0$. Then $I$ is open.
Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $f\geq y$.

Finally, as $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x=+\infty$ and as $f\geq y$, we can say that $f$ tends to $+\infty$ when $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: @AlexM. $\arctan f \ge \arctan y = \arctan x$ implies $f\ge y=x$ inasmuch the arctangent is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Alex M, I have read your post : I detailed why $f\geq y$ with another argument than yours and Dr. MV's one (though this proof is a bit longer for such a result...).

Comment: @Nicolas: Your proof shows great technical skills, but I think that it is overkill just to show that $f(x) \geq x$. It's like using a cannon to shoot birds. Congratulations, anyway.

Comment: Thank you Alex M. : I actually wrote this proof to share a usefull trick, but it is indeed a bit strong for the initial purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your inequality as $\frac {f'(x)} {1+f(x)^2} - \frac 1 {1+x^2} \geq 0$, which is equivalent to $(\arctan f(x) - \arctan x)' \geq 0$. Let $F(x)=\arctan f(x) - \arctan x$. Note that $F(0) = 0$ because $f(0)=0$. Your result will be an immediate consequence once we prove the following: "if $F' \geq 0$ and $F(0)=0$ then $F \geq 0$". But this is obvious since $F' \geq 0$ means that $F$ is increasing, so $F(x) \geq F(0) = 0 \space \forall x \geq 0$.

Therefore, $\arctan f(x) \geq \arctan x$ and since $\arctan$ is increasing, this means that $f(x) \geq x$, so $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} f(x)= \infty$.

Comment: Well done!  And glad I was able to help.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I do not know whether this is really what you had in mind (apparently Nicolas meant something different). I've written it mostly to clarify my own ideas.

Comment: It is quite close to the way forward to which I had eluded.  Anyway, well written.